# Laravel 4.2 Migrations - Alter decimal precision and scale without dropping column

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I wish to increase decimal precision and scale for a decimal column.

I am aware that I can drop the column, and re-create it, but doing so will mean losing the data in the column.

Is there a way using Laravel Schema::table that I can alter the precision and scale of the column without dropping it?

e.g. something like:

```
Schema::table('prices', function(Blueprint $t) {
    $t->buy_price->decimal(5,2);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create another `migration` and in the `up` method add following code:

```php
public function up()
{
    // Change db_name and table_name
    DB::select(DB::raw('ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `buy_price` `buy_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL;'));

}
```

Also in the `down` method just set the old value so you can `roll-back`:

```php
public function down()
{
    // Change db_name and table_name
    DB::select(DB::raw('ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `buy_price` `buy_price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL;'));

}
```

Then migrate as usual from the `terminal/command prompt` using `php artisan migrate`.

Comment: Silly me!!! I get so wrapped up in using laravel specific features, that I forget that I can do normal SQL queries and normal PHP stuff!!! Thanks. Accepted and up-voted

Answer (score 8):

this worked for me:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('prices', function(Blueprint $t) {
        $t->decimal('buy_price', 5, 2)->change();
    });
}
```

when rolling back use original precision values of **3, 1** instead

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('prices', function(Blueprint $t) {
        $t->decimal('buy_price', 3, 1)->change();
    });
}
```

I avoid DB specific "raw" statements as they might fail when I change to another DBMS engine. So I let Laravel handle necessary syntax when working w/DB

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me, using select gives me a `General Error: 2053` because select expects aa array to be returned. I'm not sure if it's the version of MySQL, or a windows/linux thing.

I had to use `DB:statement` instead:

```
public function up()
{
    // Change db_name and table_name
    DB::statement(DB::raw('ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `buy_price` `buy_price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL;'));   
}
```

and

```
public function down()
{
    // Change db_name and table_name
    DB::statement(DB::raw('ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `buy_price` `buy_price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL;'));
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who comes across this.